# Policy-based wss4j jax-ws handler without cfx/axis2/metro

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, ws-security

Is there any open-source jax-ws handler that implements policy-based WS-Security that does not depend on cxf or axis2 ?

My main use case is to implement webservice clients, but using cxf or axis2 implies that I have to bring a lot of libraries just to use wss4j.

Ideally, I´d like to depend only on wss4j + neethi and crypto packages.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I have currently the same problem that I do not want to migrate to Axis or CXF just for WS.

Comment: It's been a looong time since I've posted this question... I'm sorry to say that I've never found a solution.